# How to sniff network traffic while on VPN?

Tags: python, networking, vpn, scapy, packet-sniffers

Using `scapy` I am able to sniff the UDP network traffic between port 10 and 20 like shown in this simple code example:

```py
from scapy.all import *

def capture_traffic(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(IP) and packet.haslayer(UDP):
        if 10 <= packet[UDP].sport <= 20:
            print(f"Remote Address: {packet[IP].src} | Remote Port: {packet[UDP].sport}")

sniff(filter="udp and portrange 10-20", prn=capture_traffic)
```

However, when I launch my VPN (Windscribe), my Python script (that is running with Administrator privilege) is not able to sniff any packet. Why and how am I able to sniff packets while on VPN?

Comment: Where are you listening?  `scapy` listens to particular network interfaces.  If you're listening on the VPN's interface, then naturally you won't see any local traffic.

Comment: I was under impression that if I don't specify the interface, it will listen to *all* interface.

Comment: No, it listens by default to the `conf.iface` interface